# How do I handle debounced (using RxJs debounceTime) event emitter with Cypress?

Tags: angular, rxjs, cypress, eventemitter, debouncing

I am trying to write tests for a page that has a list of items and a search-filter. The search-filter filters the list of items based on what is input into the search-filter's text input. It operates by emitting an event when the value of the text input changes. This event is debounced using RxJs debounceTime. The search-filter component also has a button to clear the text of search.

```js
  
  private searchStringChanged: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  this.searchStringChanged.pipe(
      debounceTime(250),
  ).subscribe((searchString: string) => {
      this.filterChange.emit(searchString);
  });
  
  public handleClearInput() {
    this.searchString = '';
    this.searchStringChanged.next(this.searchString);
  }
```

My issue is that I do not see the result of clearing of the text input in my Cypress tests. I would like to clear the search-filter before every test, so I start each test with the full list of items:

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
      cy.clock();
      searchFilter.getTextInput().clear();
      cy.clock().then(clock => {
          clock.tick(1000);
          clock.restore();
      });
  });
```

I've tried a couple variations of the above code to no avail.

Using: Cypress 4.3.0, RxJs: 6.5.3

Comment: Cypress will wait for more than 250ms by default, what's the output you're trying to test?

Comment: I'm just expecting the original list of items at the beginning of test. At the end of thebeforeEach(), I see that the text input has been cleared, but the list of items are still what was at the end of the previous test.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's usually recommended not to use `cy.wait`, in this case I found it to be the only viable solution as Cypress can't know that you have a debounce, so you're safe just using:

`cy.wait(1000) // debounceTime`

It's important to also understand that the reason Cypress don't recommend to use wait with an arbitrary number is because you can't actually know how much time things will take.

If you use `cy.wait` to wait for a network requests, it might sometimes take 2 seconds, and sometimes more. Even if you use your own data things can fluctuate and change because it depends on the environment you run it and different factors.

However in your case, you're simply waiting for a debounce, something that's constant, which is why it's safe to use.

Comment: I know time has passed and this might have been the solution at the time, but nowadays use `cy.clock()` and `cy.tick(1000)` to achieve this. This works without actually waiting for the execution to run, but rather skips time.